# Wolfram|Alpha: Calculate an expression for $x^2y=-2$

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I would like to calculate the expression $(xy)^8*x^8$ knowing that $x^2y=-2$.
What should I write in Wolfram Alpha to get the expected result?

Kind regards,
Alexis.

Comment: Hint: $x^2y=(xy)x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that $$y=-\frac{2}{x^2}$$ you will get

$$\left(x\left(-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)\right)^8x^8=…$$
For your further work: The result is $$256$$
In WA you can use the replace Operator:  $$(xy)^8x^8/.y->-2/x^2$$

Comment: Ok, i understand, i have added a line to do this with WA